# Laravel 5.7 login redirects to 404 page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, captcha

I'm having an issue now after installing [laravel-math-captcha](https://github.com/elic-dev/laravel-math-captcha) though it was working fine for 2 days with Laravel 5.7 when I login with correct credentials I get redirected to a 404 page. I debug the login process

```
die($this->sendLoginResponse($request));
```

and I get

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache, private Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 13:01:35 GMT Location: http://127.0.0.1:9500/404 Redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:9500/404.
```

**When I navigate to /home I find that I successfully logged in**

Any idea how to solve this issue and why did it appear?

**[Update]**

LoginController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

  public $decayMinutes = 1;
  public $maxAttempts = 10;

  use AuthenticatesUsers;

  protected $redirectTo = '/';

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
  }

}
```

Login function from AuthenticatesUsers

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: Disable the package and see if the error goes away. If not, then you need to debug further inside `sendLoginResponse` method.

Comment: removed and still redirected to 404

Comment: Check in your home controller for any gate check

Answer (score 0):

I think your `form action url` is wrong, could you update your post and show us how you built your form? If you take a look at the response you got, you can clearly see that you called `404` page. If this is not the case, then please include the `LoginController` code too

Try and change the line inside the `LoginController` to:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Comment: it's the built in form the default one

Comment: Can you give us the code from `sendLoginResponse` then?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you would need to check your routes.php.

Probably the error is there, if you could upload your routes.php would be good.

But consider the comment above.

You are redirecting to '/' in the controller, you need to make sure that in routes.php you have assigned a view to '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Created a custom login controller which was working fine then checked the built-in login form and it just worked without any changes. The protected $redirectTo = '/'; as the same as before.